# spring security 3.1 destroys existing session with active user logged in

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

I have an application with spring security 3.1 and Ldap integration. Below are the key points in the requirement and implementation so far:

1. The application will have multiple roles for single user but these
   roles does not exist in ldap, so the application authenticates only
   the username(or userid) from ldap.
2. The roles are stored separately in the database
3. Upon successful authentication from ldap, the userdetails and the roles are set into principal object custom userdetails object by implementing UserDetailsService

Problem:

1. User A logs in the application
2. User B logs in the application, User A session is getting destroyed(which should not have happened because User A has not logged out yet!)
3. User B logs out User A gets page not found, since its session is already destroyed when User B logged in.

The applicationContext-security.xml looks like this:

```
<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
    <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="true" /> 
</beans:bean>   

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/login.jsp?login_error=2" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/login.jsp" />
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="logoutEventBroadcaster" />
            <beans:bean id="securityContextLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_logout" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class="com.*.security.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter">  
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />     
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="adAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="adAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="*.*.net" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://*.*.net:389/" />
    <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper">
        <beans:bean class="com.ezadvice.service.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper" />
    </beans:property>       
    <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp?login_error=1" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/home.do" />
    <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="migrateSessionAttributes" value="false" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

The CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter class looks like this:

```
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    String roleId = request.getParameter("roleId");
    String username = request.getParameter("j_username");
    TbEzaLoginHistory tbEzaLoginHistory = null;

    // check if the user has authority for the role
    TbEzaUser tbEzaUser = userManagementService.checkUserAndRole(roleId, username);
    if (null != tbEzaUser) {
        tbEzaLoginHistory = userManagementService.saveLoginHistory(tbEzaUser, roleId);
        request.setAttribute("loginHistoryId", tbEzaLoginHistory.getLoginKey());
        request.setAttribute("roleId", roleId);
        request.setAttribute("j_username", username);
        if (UserTracker.increment(username, roleId)) {
            try{
            Authentication attemptAuthentication = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
            if (null != attemptAuthentication) {
                CustomUser principal = (CustomUser) attemptAuthentication.getPrincipal();
                if (null == principal && null != tbEzaLoginHistory)
                        userManagementService.deleteFromLoginHistory(tbEzaLoginHistory.getLoginKey());  
                return attemptAuthentication;
            } 
            }
            catch (CommunicationException e) {
                userManagementService.deleteFromLoginHistory(tbEzaLoginHistory.getLoginKey());  
                UserTracker.decrement(username, roleId);        
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp?login_error=5");                    
                try {
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                } catch (ServletException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
                LOGGER.debug("Connection Timeout error for UserName:"+username +"\n" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }

        }else {
            if (null != tbEzaLoginHistory)
                userManagementService.deleteFromLoginHistory(tbEzaLoginHistory.getLoginKey());
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp?login_error=4");
            try {
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp?login_error=3");
        try {
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug(EXITLOGGER + " attemptAuthentication");
    }

    return null;

}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authResult;
    WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) token.getDetails();
    String address = details.getRemoteAddress();
    CustomUser user = (CustomUser) authResult.getPrincipal();
    String userName = user.getUsername();
    System.out.println("Successful login from remote address: " + address + " by username: "+ userName);
}


@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {      
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug(ENTRYLOGGER + " unsuccessfulAuthentication");
    }
    try {           
        Long loginHistoryId = (Long) request.getAttribute("loginHistoryId");
        String username = (String) request.getAttribute("j_username");
        String roleId = (String) request.getAttribute("roleId");
        userManagementService.deleteFromLoginHistory(loginHistoryId);
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
        UserTracker.decrement(username, roleId);            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug(EXITLOGGER + " unsuccessfulAuthentication");
    }
}
```

The UserTracker class looks like this:

```
public class UserTracker {
private static Set<String> loggedInUsersDetails = new HashSet<String>();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
synchronized public static boolean increment(String userName, String roleId) {  
    if(loggedInUsersDetails.add(userName.toLowerCase()+'~'+roleId)){
        return true;
    }else 
        return false;

    }       

synchronized public static void decrement(String userName, String roleId) {    
    loggedInUsersDetails.remove(userName.toLowerCase()+'~'+roleId);  
    }
```

Can anyone help me to find out, why the User A's session is getting destroyed ?

Comment: Maybe an application scope/singleton bean (non thread safe) bean holding a reference to the session ? (reference to user A session is dropped as soon as user B log in)

Comment: I am assuming that the spring security will take care of making the application thread safe. Or is there some thing that I need to set ?

Comment: I think that spring code is thread safe (even if I remember a bug like this is spring MVC... but it as been fixed). I was more thinking about something in your own code.

Comment: Show code of your custom beans.

Comment: I have added my CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter above.

Answer (score 1):

In the [docs (SavedRequests and the RequestCache Interface)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#request-caching), they talk about ExceptionTranslationFilter job to cache the current request before invoking the AuthenticationEntryPoint. This allows the request to be restored - by the SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler (which is the default).

But I've noted another evel filter: RequestCacheAwareFilter.

AFTER the redirection to the origional request, the RequestCacheAwareFilter is invoked by the chain, and he calls 'getMatchingRequest()', that gets the request, and then removes it from the cache! then, when the second authentication succeeds (from the 2nd user), there is no URL in the cache, so Spring does not know where to redirect me to. so I believe this is the root-cause of the problem.

I've found out that this issue was born due to this jira:
[SEC-1241: SavedRequest not destroyed after successful authentication](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1241?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

Comment: I was able to trace a similar thing, but I am not sure how to resolve this issue

Comment: it is something in Spring's internals... not sure there is a work-around :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can move your authentication code into **custom AuthenticationManager**. AuthenticationManager will have two dependencies on **LdapAuthenticationProvider** and **DaoAuthenticationProvider**. During authentication processing it will be responsible for:

- calling LDAP provider
- calling DB provider
- combining two authentication objects into one (credentials from LDAP and roles from DB).

Comment: I have done a similar code  using CustomUserDetailsContextMapper class which implements UserDetailsContextMapper, by first authenticating from ldap and then calling the db provider. But I will give a try to the above solution as well

Comment: What is the main reason behind your CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter?

Comment: The reason behind this filter was to first check the user if it is a valid user and with the correct role. Also we had noticed that concurrency control was not working, so we had to write UserTracker class to maintain that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution to the above problem. There were multiple causes:

1. While testing the above problem I was making a mistake, that I was trying to achieve concurrency control when users opens the application in a tabbed browser.
2. Spring internally stores the ip address of the machine to prevent multiple users to login from same machine. Thus had to make code changes so that user's having multiple roles are not allowed to login from the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
```

at

```
<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="migrateSessionAttributes" value="false" />
</beans:bean>
```